# How to add TinyMCE3 custom plugin to DRUPAL 6

Tags: tinymce, drupal-6

I have [this](https://drupal.org/project/wysiwyg) module installed and I wanna add a custom plugin to TinyMCE editor. It does not add any button to the editor but it adds a feature where users can right click on a word inside the editor and plugin provides an option to add that word to a custom dictionary and my module will take care of.

How can I add a custom plugin to tinyMCE?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone. I found a detailed solution here and it works with no problem.
https://drupal.org/node/2237761

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hava a look here: https://drupal.org/node/1270714

This comment there might help you:

> See wysiwyg.api.php. With a small Drupal module you can implement
>   hook_wysiwyg_editor_settings_alter() to override most properties on
>   the settings object passed to the editor instance on init. There's
>   also hook_wysiwyg_plugin() which allows you to specify where
>   additional plugins/extensions can be loaded from and if they have any
>   buttons or not. Implementing this hook will let you list the plugin
>   (if it's a button-less extensions) or its buttons under "Buttons and
>   plugins" on the editor profile configuration page.
>
> Writing such a module often takes no more than a few minutes, so I can
>   put together the code if you link to the plugin you need. If you'd
>   like to try yourself first, I recently posted code for another TinyMCE
>   plugin over at #1248704: Adding a simple plugin.